# dealing with web.py sessions with subapp?

Tags: session, web.py, subapplication

I have read http://webpy.org/cookbook/sessions_with_subapp.
The session works fine while I 
have only one app, but when I create a sub app, I am encountering error ~ ,details below:

The **main.py**:

```webctx
import web
from sub import subapp
web.config.debug = False

urls = ("/sub",subapp,"/", "count",)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

db = web.database(dbn='sqlite', db='./session.db')
store = web.session.DBStore(db, 'sessions')
session = web.session.Session(app, store, initializer={'count': 0})

def session_hook():
    web.ctx.session = session

app.add_processor(web.loadhook(session_hook))

class count:
    def GET(self):
        session.count += 1
        return str(session.count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The **subapp.py**:

```cs
import web

urls = ("/", "count",)

subapp = web.application(urls, globals())

session = web.ctx.session

class count:
    def GET(self):
        session.count += 1
        return str(session.count)
```

Errors while try to run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sub import subapp
  File "/tmp/session/sub.py", line 9, in <module>
    session = web.ctx.session
AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'session'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply assign `session = web.ctx.session` because this line is executed only during app initialization but `ctx` attributes are only accessible at request time. You may `from web import ctx` and then use `ctx.session` instead of `session` in all subapps.

***subapp.py*** example:

```cs
import web
from web import ctx

urls = (
    "/", "count",
)

subapp = web.application(urls, globals())

class count:
    def GET(self):
        ctx.session.count += 1
        return str(ctx.session.count)
```

Comment: You can use `ctx` only from controller methods and loadhooks.